# which database to use in Scala (and examples needed)

Tags: database, postgresql, scala, jdbc

I am new to Scala.

Which database connectivity is best supported in Scala? I am also looking for complete examples to access a database (authenticate, connect, query, extract result)

I have a table MyTable with two columns (Value1, Value2) in a database MyDB, which I need to access.

I have been thinking of postgresql, so some examples using this would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362748/wanted-good-examples-of-scala-database-persistence)  and you will get all answers of your questions.